# How can I add class active if the element click on the vue component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```js
Vue.component('list-category', {
  template: "#lc",
  props: ['data', 'category', 'search'],
  data() {
    return {
      open: false,
      categoryId: this.category
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let isDataOpen = (d) => d.id === this.categoryId || d.children && d.children.some(isDataOpen);
   this.open = isDataOpen(this.data);
  },
  computed: {
    icon() {
      return {
        'fa-plus': !this.open,
        'fa-minus': this.open,
      }
    },
    isFolder() {
      return this.data.children && this.data.children.length
    },
    isShow() {
      return this.open ? 'show' : 'hide'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.open = !this.open
    },
    filterByCategory(id) {
      this.categoryId = id
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'England',
          children: [{
              id: 3,
              name: 'Chelsea',
              children: [{
                  id: 7,
                  name: 'Hazard'
                },
                {
                  id: 8,
                  name: 'Morata'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              name: 'Manchester United',
              children: [{
                  id: 9,
                  name: 'Pogba'
                },
                {
                  id: 10,
                  name: 'Lukaku'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Spain',
          children: [{
              id: 5,
              name: 'Real Madrid',
              children: [{
                  id: 11,
                  name: 'Ronaldo'
                },
                {
                  id: 12,
                  name: 'Bale'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 6,
              name: 'Barcelona',
              children: [{
                  id: 13,
                  name: 'Messi'
                },
                {
                  id: 14,
                  name: 'Suarez'
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      category: 7
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 -15px 0;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:last-child {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:focus, .pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a + ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a + ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <div class="panel panel-default pd-search-filter">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> By Category</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="filter-category" v-for="list in categories">
        <list-category :data="list" :category="category"></list-category>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="lc">
    <li>
        <!--parent-->
        <a v-if="isFolder" href="javascript:" @click="toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-fw" :class="icon"></span> {{data.name}}
        </a>
        <!--if not folding, we do not need an binding event-->
        <a v-else href="javascript:" :title="data.name" :class="{active: data.id === categoryId}" @click="filterByCategory(data.id)"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></span> {{data.name}}</a>
        <!--children-->
        <ul v-if="isFolder" :class="isShow">
            <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category="categoryId"></list-category>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

Seems you need to see demo and full code

It's like this : http://jsfiddle.net/vxLhbo5m/861/

From demo seen category hazard active. If I click on morata category, it is not active. Whereas I have made the code

How can I solve this problem?

===========================================================================

Comment: it seems like it's working for me, what is your issue?

Comment: @samayo For example : If you click morata category, Where the morata category active?

Comment: @samayo If the category active, the color change to yellow color

Comment: see these two code samples, with the three numbers: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function your issue is that you are using `data(){}` which creates a copy of your data and gives it to each component, so any click event is meaningless because that active link is not saved in the same place for all ... if it makes sense

Comment: You need to use the `this.$emit('update-active-category', id);` in `filterByCategory` method since you are trying to update data from a parent component.  Then use `@update-active-category` when using `list-category` component in order to update the category in parent app

Comment: @semayo Try to answer with the code.  I'm still confuses

Comment: @Omar Tanti  Whether you had try it first in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to move the category calculator to a watcher (instead of `mount()`) and emit/listen to some events from child to parent to update the category and **collapse** the non-selected sub-tree.

**[Updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/vxLhbo5m/916/)**.

Changes:

- Template:

  - Parent:

    - From:

      ```
      <div id="app">
          ...
              <list-category :data="list" :category="category"></list-category>
      ```
    - Adding listening to the `category` event and updating the `category` property at parent:

      ```
      <div id="app">
          ...
              <list-category :data="list" :category="category" @category="category = $event"></list-category>
      ```
  - Child:

    - From:

      ```
      <template id="lc">
          ...
              <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category="categoryId"></list-category>
      ```
    - Listen to the `category` event and emit it up to the parent:

      ```
      <template id="lc">
          ...
              <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category="categoryId" @category="$emit('category', $event)"></list-category>
      ```
- JavaScript (all in child):

  - Change `filterByCategory` to emit event instead of mutating property:

    - From:

      ```
      filterByCategory(id) {
        this.categoryId = id
      }
      ```
    - To:

      ```
      filterByCategory(id) {
        this.$emit('category', id);
      }
      ```
  - Remove `mounted` hook and add watcher:

    - Remove mounted:

      ```
      mounted() {
        let isDataOpen = (d) => d.id === this.categoryId || d.children && d.children.some(isDataOpen);
        this.open = isDataOpen(this.data);
      },
      ```
    - Add watcher to pick up when `category` changes in the parent:

      ```
      watch: {
        category: {
          handler() {
            this.categoryId = this.category
            let isDataOpen = (d) => d.id === this.categoryId || d.children && d.children.some(isDataOpen);
            this.open = isDataOpen(this.data);
          },
          immediate: true
        }
      }
      ```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('list-category', {
  template: "#lc",
  props: ['data', 'category', 'search'],
  data() {
    return {
      open: false,
      categoryId: this.category
    }
  },
  computed: {
    icon() {
      return {
        'fa-plus': !this.open,
        'fa-minus': this.open,
      }
    },
    isFolder() {
      return this.data.children && this.data.children.length
    },
    isShow() {
      return this.open ? 'show' : 'hide'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.open = !this.open
    },
    filterByCategory(id) {
      this.$emit('category', id);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    category: {
     handler() {
        this.categoryId = this.category
       let isDataOpen = (d) => d.id === this.categoryId || d.children && d.children.some(isDataOpen);
       this.open = isDataOpen(this.data);
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'England',
          children: [{
              id: 3,
              name: 'Chelsea',
              children: [{
                  id: 7,
                  name: 'Hazard'
                },
                {
                  id: 8,
                  name: 'Morata'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              name: 'Manchester United',
              children: [{
                  id: 9,
                  name: 'Pogba'
                },
                {
                  id: 10,
                  name: 'Lukaku'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Spain',
          children: [{
              id: 5,
              name: 'Real Madrid',
              children: [{
                  id: 11,
                  name: 'Ronaldo'
                },
                {
                  id: 12,
                  name: 'Bale'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 6,
              name: 'Barcelona',
              children: [{
                  id: 13,
                  name: 'Messi'
                },
                {
                  id: 14,
                  name: 'Suarez'
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      category: 7
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 -15px 0;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:last-child {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:focus, .pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a + ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a + ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <div class="panel panel-default pd-search-filter">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> By Category</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="filter-category" v-for="list in categories">
        <list-category :data="list" :category="category" @category="category = $event"></list-category>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="lc">
    <li>
        <!--parent-->
        <a v-if="isFolder" href="javascript:" @click="toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-fw" :class="icon"></span> {{data.name}}
        </a>
        <!--if not folding, we do not need an binding event-->
        <a v-else href="javascript:" :title="data.name" :class="{active: data.id === categoryId}" @click="filterByCategory(data.id)"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></span> {{data.name}}</a>
        <!--children-->
        <ul v-if="isFolder" :class="isShow">
            <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category="categoryId" @category="$emit('category', $event)"></list-category>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems there is still a problem If I run your script above, the hazard category active (yellow color). If I click morata category, it had add class active in the element. But the morata category has not changed to yellow. If I click to another element, the morata category looks change to yellow

Comment: The morata does is yellow. Try in the demo above. Click morata then click somewhere else outside the demo iframe.

Comment: Yes, it works. But why the element does not immediately turn yellow when diclick?

Comment: Because when you click it, you focus it. And the focus style `.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:focus`  turns it gray. To remove it, just remove the such style: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/vxLhbo5m/917/ (just removed the style with `:focus` at line 23 of CSS)

Comment: In your jsfiddle is no error. But if I implement in my case, there still error. The error like this : `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "category"`. Whereas I had follow your code

Comment: Whenever you have a `<list-category>` you should have like: `<list-category ... @category="$emit('category', $event)">`. Except for the outermost (the first one that uses `<list-category>`). In this outermost you should have `<list-category ...  @category="category = $event"></list-category>`. Since my example have only two "levels" (the parent and the child) you see one example of each case. In your real scenario, you probably have more levels, so you probably need more cases like `<list-category ... @category="$emit('category', $event)">` in the intermediary components. Makes sense?

Comment: I am still confused what do you mean. But I have implemented your code into my case. My case is exactly the same as your jsfiddle. In the parent component like this : `<list-category :data="list" :category="category" @category="category = $event"></list-category>`. In the child component like this : `<list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category="categoryId" @category="$emit('category', $event)"></list-category>`

Comment: In your parent, `category` is not a `data` variable, yes? It must be a prop. If that's the case, change `@category="category = $event"` to `@category="$emit('category', $event)"` and add in whoever uses the parent like: `<parentname @category="category = $event" ...>`.

Comment: In summary, any component that receives `category` as prop must have `@category="$emit('category', $event)"`. The component that has `category` as its data (and not as a prop it received from its parent) should have `@category="category = $event"`.

Comment: Btw, on a side note, I really suggest you take some minutes and check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html . It will really help you out.

Comment: Is there no other way? Because my parent category called from the view laravel (I collaborate laravel framework and vue js). If this : `@category="category = $event"` called from view laravel, seems it does not work. I find another way. For example I make prop category into data category. Is it possible?

Comment: Solve. I save prop category into data category. It works

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the data of a parent element from the child component.  In order to change the parent's data yyou would need to emit the change to the parent and than change the data from the parent.

Please find the below to have an idea how to use the `this.$emit`.  I know I had to change the json data to avoid recursive calls to the same template, but now you have an idea on how to change the parent data element.

```js
Vue.component('list-category', {
  template: "#lc",
  props: ['data', 'category', 'search'],
  data() {
    return {
      open: false,
      categoryId: this.category
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let isDataOpen = (d) => d.id === this.categoryId || d.children && d.children.some(isDataOpen);
   this.open = isDataOpen(this.data);
  },
  computed: {
    icon() {
      return {
        'fa-plus': !this.open,
        'fa-minus': this.open,
      }
    },
    isFolder() {
      return this.data.children && this.data.children.length
    },
    isShow() {
      return this.open ? 'show' : 'hide'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.open = !this.open
    },
    filterByCategory: function(id){
      this.$emit('update-active-category', id);
      console.log('Emitting: ' + id);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
return {
  categories: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'England',
      children: [{
          id: 3,
          name: 'Chelsea',
          children: [{
              id: 7,
              name: 'Hazard'
            },
            {
              id: 8,
              name: 'Morata'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Manchester United',
          children: [{
              id: 9,
              name: 'Pogba'
            },
            {
              id: 10,
              name: 'Lukaku'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Spain',
      children: [{
          id: 5,
          name: 'Real Madrid',
          children: [{
              id: 11,
              name: 'Ronaldo'
            },
            {
              id: 12,
              name: 'Bale'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'Barcelona',
          children: [{
              id: 13,
              name: 'Messi'
            },
            {
              id: 14,
              name: 'Suarez'
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
    category: 7
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateActiveCategory: function(id) {
    this.category = id;
  }
}
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow !important;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 -15px 0;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:last-child {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:focus, .pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a + ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.pd-search-filter > .panel-body ul.filter-category > li a + ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <div class="panel panel-default pd-search-filter">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> By Category</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="filter-category" v-for="list in categories">
        <list-category :data="list" :category="category" @update-active-category="updateActiveCategory">
        </list-category>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="lc">
    <li>
        <!--parent-->
        <a v-if="isFolder" href="javascript:" @click="toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-fw" :class="icon"></span> {{data.name}}
        </a>
        <!--if not folding, we do not need an binding event-->
        <a v-else href="javascript:" :title="data.name" :class="{active: data.id === category}" @click="filterByCategory(data.id)" @update-active-category="filterByCategory"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></span> {{data.name}}</a>
        <!--children-->
        <ul v-if="isFolder" :class="isShow">
            <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category="category" @update-active-category="filterByCategory"></list-category>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer is not like my case. I did not get an answer from your answer

Comment: You cannot accomplish what you want without the emit . I just explained how the emit works, you need to change the structure of you components and use the emit function.  I will not restructure the code for you, but I think you have to separate the folder component and list-category-item  separetly. 
 Your question was to to add an active class and I just did.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you that my answer could be edited and solve your issue.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will check it